# AddSpaStaticFiles 'RootPath' silently breaks HMR of webpack devServer

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, asp.net-core-2.2, vue-cli-3

Webpack configured to work in two steps:

- output 'ClientApp/build/public' for client build and assets (target web),
- output 'ClientApp/build/server' for SSR build (target node).

Dev Server runned in proxy mode: `spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("https://localhost:8080/");`.

Hot Module Replace works when I set in Startup.cs, `ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build/";
});
```

In browser's concole:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
...
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
```

But with current setting I've get the 'server' folder visible and can access `https://localhost:44318/server/server.bundle.js`

When I trying to set the RootPath as `ClientApp/build/public/` application still works and no access to server files - desired behavior, but no any errors or status info from HMR in browser console. It silently missing (but still exists inlined in the client bundle).

Dev Server as separated process not stopped at all time - just toggle RootPath in .net project to enable or miss HMR. What's wrong?

Dev Server config:

```
devServer: {

    disableHostCheck: true,

    https: true,
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/localhost.pfx'),
    pfxPassphrase: 'some-password',

    overlay: {
        warnings: true,
        errors: true
    },

    clientLogLevel: 'info'
}
```

Comment: Clarification: HMR works _only_ when `AddSpaStaticFiles` called in `ConfigureServices` with RootPath at one level above the output folder. Even if I _do not call_ UseSpaStaticFiles.

Comment: Any non-existing folder as RootPath enables the HMR. So, use SpaStaticFiles only in production. Development Server as a proxy provides all static files itself. Maybe someone can explain this?